# Диапазон времени

Tags: javascript

```
var offset = new Date ($('body').data('date'))

function secToTime(sec){ 
    dt = new Date(); 
    dt.setTime(sec*1000); 
    return dt.getUTCHours()+3+":"+dt.getUTCMinutes()+":"+dt.getUTCSeconds(); 
} 
var time = secToTime(offset )
```

Мне нужно выводить модальное окно в определенный диапазон времени, например с `8:00` до `00:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var now = new Date
console.log(now.getHours() >= 20)
```

Comment: `var` в наш век продвинутых технологий? :)

Comment: @Other, а я люблю `var` :)

Comment: @Other а у сколько процентов пользователей сайт не навернётся из-за использования нового стандарта, включающего `let`? Лично я так и не удосужился этот вопрос изучить, а проблемы на ровном месте создавать не хочется.

Comment: @Regent, `let` ещё и работает медленнее. По крайней мере, год назад так было.

Comment: @Regent, у [16,82%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) накроется

Comment: @Other прошу прощения , как мне написать условие , если пользователь зашел на сайт в диапозоне времени с 00:00 до 10:00 включительно, и вывести модальное окно с сообщением?

Comment: @Other с учетом того, что между `var` и `let` есть разница и их надо знать - то слепое изменение всех var на let может аукнуться

Comment: @gbrgbr, `now.getHours() < 10`

Comment: @Other 
var offset = new Date ($('body').data('date'))

function secToTime(sec){ 
    dt = new Date(); 
    dt.setTime(sec*1000); 
    return dt.getUTCHours()+3+":"+dt.getUTCMinutes()+":"+dt.getUTCSeconds(); 
 
console.log(dt.getHours() >= 20)
}  так правльно?

Comment: @gbrgbr а почему вы это спрашиваете у Other? И пример кода лучше в JSFiddle (или ему подобном сервисе) разместить - в комментариях код читается с большим трудом.

Comment: @Qwertiy но, насколько я понял, читая ответы к [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467642/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-let-and-var), не настолько медленнее, чтобы это имело значение в большинстве случаев. А ещё не знаю насчет корректности тестов в принятом ответе (не вчитывался в код), но "_let inside an if()_" у меня вывел результат на порядок лучше чем "_var inside an if()_".

Comment: @АлексейШиманский слепое - да, но, в принципе, толково написанный код не должен пострадать при переезде с `var` на `let`.

Comment: @Regent не согласен. потому что писали исходя из одного стандартного поведения, а при переходе получается другое. Это как на легковушку вазовскую привинчивать колеса от трактора беларусь. И то и то - колёса. Но вот радиус-то различается.

Comment: @Regent, стандарт уже довольно старый, большинство обновилось, остальные не делают этого на свой риск, может баги вынудят обновится.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, автор ответа знает разницу, так что понимает что тут можно.

Comment: @gbrgbr, Вам показали пример: из текущего объекта берём текущий час и просто сравниваем: `if(currentHour >= 8)` (больше 8 - истина, как наступит полночь - будет ложь, то, что нужно).